# Edit the HTML dashboard in JMeter 5.1

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I basically want to get few things removed from the HTML report like the APDEX table, Network from Statistics. Can we customize it as per our requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit file bin/report-template/index.html.fmkr

This is a freemarker template file, you can remove apdex or irrelevant divs from file

I would keep a copy of original version